# 6 times high pitch double beeps after login to Ubuntu 21.04 on Dell XPS 9750

Tags: nvidia, sound, login, dell, 21.04

After I login to Ubuntu 21.04 it plays six times a double high pitch beep sound from the speaker. So it's not on boot, it's after I logged in. There is no error message popping up. First I assumed that this must be a DELL error beep, but it should come while booting the system, not after login. I've ran the DELL diagnostic, but it doesn't find any error. I also realized that sometimes it's not loading the Nvidia GPU, just the Intel one, and if I let the laptop alone for a few minutes, it simply freezes. I think that it might be the problem with the CMOS battery, but if you have an other idea what it could be, pls. let me know.